# How to apply tranition to a left align element?

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, flex4, flex3

My project has a panel aligned to right:

```
<s:BorderContainer id="panelRight" right="0" top="60" bottom="30" width="333">
```

When I execute that code

```
move.target = panelRight;
move.xBy = +panelRight.width;
move.play();
```

Nothing happens: this is because the panelRighti saligned to right !

How can I solve that ?

Answer (score 0):

You could use `Animate` class instead of `Move` and add effect not for `x` but `right` property. It will be looks like:

```
var moveEffect:Animate = new Animate();
moveEffect.target = panelRight;
moveEffect.motionPaths = Vector.<MotionPath>([new SimpleMotionPath("right", null, null, -panelRight.width)]);
moveEffect.play();
```

The effect will be looks same.

[Animate class](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/spark/effects/Animate.html)